# Mudar saída do resultado em da tag span para tag input

Tags: javascript, maskmoney

Bom dia grande amigos, me deparei com esta situação, Achei um post aqui que resolveu uma boa parte do meu problema porem estou em um projeto da faculdade e o professor solicitou foi intensivo em input, porem a resposta do calculo esta esta sendo mostrada em uma tag SPAN e não estou conseguindo fazer o resultado sair em um input.

Se eu criar o input e por o ID="resultado" o script para de funcionar, alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue Codigo abaixo:

```js
// Remove pontos, vírgulas, espaços e marcadores de moeda.
function limpar(x) {
return x.replace(",", "").replace(".", "").replace("R$", "").replace(" ", "");
}

// Recebe um número inteiro (valor em centavos) e devolve uma string com o
// seu valor formatado como se fosse um valor monetário em real.
function formatarMoeda(numero) {

if (isNaN(numero)) return "Valor Incorreto";

// Descobre se o valor é negativo e extrai o sinal.
var negativo = numero < 0;
numero = Math.abs(numero);

// Usado para produzir a resposta, caractere por caractere.
var resposta = "";

// Converte o número para string.
var t = numero + "";

// Itera cada caractere do número, de trás para frente.
for (var i = t.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var j = t.length - i;

    // Adiciona o caractere na resposta.
    resposta = t.charAt(i) + resposta;

    // Colocar uma vírgula ou um ponto se for o caso.
    if (j == 2) {
        resposta = "," + resposta;
    } else if (j % 3 == 2 && i != 0) {
        resposta = "." + resposta;
    }
}

// Preenche os zeros a esquerda para o caso de o valor ser muito pequeno (menos de um real).
if (resposta.length < 4) {
    resposta = "0,00".substring(0, 4 - resposta.length) + resposta;
}
 
// Coloca o sinal de negativo, se necessário.
if (negativo) resposta = "-" + resposta;

// Coloca como prefixo a unidade da moeda.
return resposta;
}

function somar() {
// Obtém os dois valores digitados.
var a = parseInt(limpar($("#campo1").val()), 10);
var b = parseInt(limpar($("#campo2").val()), 10);

// Executa a soma.
var soma = a + b;

// Formata o resultado como moeda.
var resposta = formatarMoeda(soma);
$("#resultado").html(resposta);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form>
<input class="title" type="text" id="campo1" onkeyup="somar()" />
<input class="title"  type="text" id="campo2" value="R$ 2,87" onkeyup="somar()"/>
   <span class="title" onkeyup="somar()" id="resultado"></span> <br><br>
<input class="title" type="text" id="Total" onkeyup="somar()" /> //Meu objetivo e que o resultado saia neste input <br><br>

</form>

<div id="testes"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o campo onde você quer apresentar o resultado tem id="Total". O correto seria na funçã somar() alterar o $("#resultado").html(resposta) por $("#Total").val(resposta).
Segue o código:

```js
// Remove pontos, vírgulas, espaços e marcadores de moeda.
function limpar(x) {
return x.replace(",", "").replace(".", "").replace("R$", "").replace(" ", "");
}

// Recebe um número inteiro (valor em centavos) e devolve uma string com o
// seu valor formatado como se fosse um valor monetário em real.
function formatarMoeda(numero) {

if (isNaN(numero)) return "Valor Incorreto";

// Descobre se o valor é negativo e extrai o sinal.
var negativo = numero < 0;
numero = Math.abs(numero);

// Usado para produzir a resposta, caractere por caractere.
var resposta = "";

// Converte o número para string.
var t = numero + "";

// Itera cada caractere do número, de trás para frente.
for (var i = t.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var j = t.length - i;

    // Adiciona o caractere na resposta.
    resposta = t.charAt(i) + resposta;

    // Colocar uma vírgula ou um ponto se for o caso.
    if (j == 2) {
        resposta = "," + resposta;
    } else if (j % 3 == 2 && i != 0) {
        resposta = "." + resposta;
    }
}

// Preenche os zeros a esquerda para o caso de o valor ser muito pequeno (menos de um real).
if (resposta.length < 4) {
    resposta = "0,00".substring(0, 4 - resposta.length) + resposta;
}
 
// Coloca o sinal de negativo, se necessário.
if (negativo) resposta = "-" + resposta;

// Coloca como prefixo a unidade da moeda.
return resposta;
}

function somar() {
// Obtém os dois valores digitados.
var a = parseInt(limpar($("#campo1").val()), 10);
var b = parseInt(limpar($("#campo2").val()), 10);

// Executa a soma.
var soma = a + b;

// Formata o resultado como moeda.
var resposta = formatarMoeda(soma);
$("#Total").val(resposta);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form>
<input class="title" type="text" id="campo1" onkeyup="somar()" />
<input class="title"  type="text" id="campo2" value="R$ 2,87" onkeyup="somar()"/>
   <span class="title" onkeyup="somar()" id="resultado"></span> <br><br>
<input class="title" type="text" id="Total" onkeyup="somar()" /> //Meu objetivo e que o resultado saia neste input <br><br>

</form>

<div id="testes"></div>
```

Comment: Bom dia, testado e validado muito obrigado amigo você me ajudou e muito, outra coisa sou iniciante em JavaScript, nesta questão ai do (.html) ele seria para por uma saída em um span e o (.val) seria para um resultado em input né?

Comment: exato, html seria quando vc quer inserir algo dentro de uma tag, mas o input não abre e fecha, logo não tem um html "dentro", mas ele tem o valor...só como conselho, dá uma olhada em React e Angular. Não tem nada de errado usar JS puro ou JQuery, mas com React e Angular vc vai desenvolver mais rápido. Tem um tempo de aprendizado grande, mas depois é só alegria.

Comment: Certo, vou atender seu conselho da uma estudada no React e Angular. muito obrigado. Nota 1000 pra você.